# How to check if there is a 3G software / hardware issue with phone?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-one-x, 3g

I have HTC One X running Android 4.1.1 and Sense4+. Lately my 3G service has gone pretty bad. I contacted my telecom operator but there customer service representatives aren't much help. My GPRS works flawlessly. Its only the 3G where I face issues.

I would like to know if I can check whether there is a software or hardware problem with my phone with respect to 3G.

Comment: What *exactly* is the problem? The question is a bit vague, no clear explanation, *Lately my 3G service has gone pretty bad.* Indicative of some carrier issues on their end? Poor signal reception...

Comment: @t0mm13b: The problem is that my 3G connection has become a bit finicky. But that's not the question. What I am looking for is that how can I check if there is a software / hardware problem with my handset in connecting to 3G network. Any apps on Google Play may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be my way of checking the 3G connectivity issues. Might work for you too.

1. First try to reset the APN and restart your phone.
2. If it did not work, try forcing the phone to 3G. In your
   dialer, enter `*#*#4636#*#*` -> Phone Information -> Select WCDMA only
   in the drop down menu. This should make your phone work only in 3G.
   Try testing your speeds via Speedtest for bandwidth.
3. If both steps did not solve your problem, try using a different SIM
   in which 3G is working. If this solves your problem, replace the SIM
   from Customer care.
4. Even now your problem is not solved, try factory reset your phone.
   **Warning:** This will reset everything in your phone including pictures, take a backup of your phone before proceeding further.
5. If none of the above solves your problem, take it to your HTC
   customer care to check them for hardware defect.